# Link in partial Razor Page fires wrong OnGet

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I am using a razor page to display an ItemT model and at the bottom I inserted a partial view to show all properties (which are not assigned to this model in a n:m relation).

The PageModel 'FreePropertiesToItemT' has two public properties:

```
public ItemT ItemT { get; set; }  // the one Item to show
public IList<PropertyIndexViewModel> FreeProperties { get; set; } // all free properties
```

An `OnGetAsync(int? id)` Method is called which works fine. The Page shows all data correctly.

The view displays a link for every Property:

```
<a asp-page-handler="addProperty" asp-route-id="@item.PropertyID">add</a>
```

This creates the link:

```
<a href="/Inventory/ItemTs/FreePropertiesToItemT?id=1&amp;handler=addProperty">add</a>
```

This is the correct link (I think). The route, id value and the handler are correct because there is a second OnGet Method in the PageModel:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetaddPropertyAsync(int? id)
```

However, the link only calls OnGetAsync (and not OnGetaddProppertyAsync) every time and, of course, for every Property!
What am I missing?

Model of ItemT:

```
public class ItemT
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemTID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "ItemT")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;
    public virtual ICollection<ItemTProperty> ItemTProperties { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel of free properties:

```
public class PropertyIndexViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool DefaultsOnly { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valuetype")]
    public string Valuetype { get; set; }
}
```

The Page to list one ItemT:

```
@page
@model Inventory.Areas.Inventory.Pages.ItemTs.FreePropertiesToItemTModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "FreePropertiesToItemT";
}

<h1>Free Properties</h1>

<div>
    <h4>ItemT</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemT.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemT.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemT.isActive)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemT.isActive)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ItemT.ItemTID">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
<p></p>

<div>
    @{
        ViewData["FreeProperties"] = true;
    }
    <partial name="../Properties/_Properties.cshtml" model="Model.FreeProperties" />
</div>
```

The Partial which is loaded:

```
@using Inventory.DAL.ViewModels
@model IList<PropertyIndexViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].DefaultsOnly)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Unit)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Valuetype)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DefaultsOnly)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valuetype)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (ViewBag.FreeProperties != null)
                    {
                    <a asp-page-handler="addProperty" asp-route-id="@item.PropertyID">add</a>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the c# code behind the page:

```
namespace Inventory.Areas.Inventory.Pages.ItemTs
{
    public class FreePropertiesToItemTModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

        public FreePropertiesToItemTModel(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;
        }

        public ItemT ItemT { get; set; }
        public IList<PropertyIndexViewModel> FreeProperties { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ItemT = await _uow.ItemTRepo.getById((int)id);

            if (ItemT == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }            
            FreeProperties = await _uow.PropertyRepo.getFreePropertiesForItemT((int)id);

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetaddPropertyAsync(int? id)
        {
            if( id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if(ItemT == null) { return NotFound(); }
            await _uow.ItemTRepo.addProperty(ItemT.ItemTID, (int)id);
            await _uow.Commit();
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce the issue based on the existing code .If you want the community review and debug the code , please show the complete code of the model design and the Razor pages .

Comment: The semicolon in the generated anchor tag link looks strange to me. It should be `&handler=addProperty` instead of `;handler=addProperty`

Comment: @EliasJohannes, thank you. I copied the link from the browser and it inserted the "&" as html -> &amp;   The link is generated with an &

Comment: @XueliChen: I edited my question put in all the relevant code. Thank´s for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your handler name error ,change it like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAddPropertyAsync(int? id)
```

The first letter of handler name must be capitalized , otherwise `handler=addProperty` in the url is treated as a query-string parameter not a handler name.